# Gruntjs: Loading config files based on target

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like to be able to run the same builds for different targets by passing in config information from a build file, e.g. grunt build:target1 and grunt build:target2...

I figured I could access the target within the grunt file

```
module.exports = function ( grunt ) {
  var userConfig = require( **'./'+grunt.task.current.name+'build.config.js'** );
  var taskConfig...
  grunt.initConfig( grunt.util._.extend( userConfig, taskConfig ) );
```

But the target is only available within a task.

Is there another way of accomplishing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass command line arguments to Grunt by passing them using two dashes, like
`--[your_arg_name]=[arg_value]`.

Example:

```
grunt --target=debug
```

Then retrieve this value in your Grunt config file by calling

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var target = grunt.option('target'),
        userConfig = require('./' + target + "build.config.js");
        ...
}
```

You can choose whichever name you like, I chose `target` in my examples above.